# Custom column in slick

Tags: slick

Can I have a custom column in `Slick` (I want a case class as a column which represents `JSON`).

```
case class Segment(isNative: Option[Boolean], origin: Option[List[String]],whitelist: Option[Whitelist])

def seg = column[Option[Segment]]("segment")
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can - that's the question of custom mapping. Here is how it looks if you would like to store `String` in db:

```
  implicit val segmentColumnType = MappedColumnType.base[Segment, String](
    segment => ???, // logic here to convert Segment to JSON string
    string => ??? // logic here to convert JSON string to Segment case class
  )
```

Then you define your column as follows (that's actually your code):

```
def seg = column[Option[Segment]]("segment")
```

You can use above then both in results and queries e.g. like this:

```
   MyTable
      .filter(_.segment === Segment(Some(true), None, None)
      .result
```

Just keep in mind you need to have this implicit (`segmentColumnType`) in scope in places when you use this conversation (column definition, queries etc).